# Is there a property I can use to detect when I am building with MSBuildWorkspace

Tags: msbuild, roslyn, csproj

Inside my `.csproj` file, is there a property I can use to detect the project file is being built by `MSBuildWorkspace` (as opposed to `msbuild` directly)?

Basically, I have a `csproj` file that executes an exe.

The exe takes the project file as input, builds it using MSBuildWorkspace, and then generates some additional files based on the compilation.

However, every time I build it, it is causing the csproj file to execute the exe - and so I have made myself a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)!

I want to stop this happening...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually really simple it turns out!

You can supply properties to `MSBuildWorkspace.Create` that are passed to the csproj files, e.g.:

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{   
    ["Tools_BuildingInsideGenerator"] = "true"
};

using (workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(properties))
{
}
```